# how to add filter to datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have made a dataTable and populated it with many fields, but I would like to add my own search/filter function to it.

I have a textbox that I am using as the search/filter:

```
   <div class="filterTable">
        <form>
            <input id="tableSearch" type="text" placeholder="filter">
        </form>
    </div>
```

And this is the JavaScript function that I have added for it:

```
$("tableSearch").keyup(function () {
        var string = document.getElementById("tableSearch").value;
        oTable.fnFilter(string);
    });
```

oTable is the initialized dataTable.

The problem I am having is that the JavaScript function is never hit. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the # tag for reffering the ID of an element.

Try with the below mentioned code.

```
   $("#tableSearch").keyup(function () {
        var string = $(this).val();
        oTable.fnFilter(string);
    });
```

Comment: Solved it thanks :) Cant believe that i missed the # lol 
I'll accept your answer in 7min. 
Thanks again

Comment: @BrianPeach Thanks Brian. Glad that i was able to help.